# Can harmful mirrored pairs of substances cause damage to humans?

Tags: science-based, biology, technology, humans

Basically, there are chests in rooms that each mirror another room. Each chest's contents is the opposite of the opposite room's contents.

Every chest is filled with what looks like water.

But touching the water for an extended period of time causes extreme damage to the limb that touched it. This cannot be fatal, if a limb is put in it, but can be if it comes into contact with the head/torso.

There needs to be seven pairs.

The plan so far is:

HF - NaOH (aq)

Hot glycerol - Cold acetone

Water with vibrio vulnificus (modified) - Concentrated disinfectant

Poison - Venom

Radioactive waste - Catharsis 9(Fictitious thing designed to kill cancer, but kills all cells)

Parasites - Decomposers

Stimulant - Depressant

Of these seven pairs, are they likely to cancel each other's effects out to keep a human from being harmed by them?

Comment: So you need three more? Or do you want us to suggest options for the other four as well?

Comment: Try using distilled water for the one that doesn't bubble. Bubbles are caused by impurities in the water, and removing them prevents it. This is why you shouldn't boil distilled water, as it will explode if you add any foreign contaminants.

Comment: Liquids only bubble when they are at their boiling point. You can easily have unpressurised liquid at above 100 degrees, as long as it's not water. I'm sure there's something out there that looks like water but boils way above 100.

Comment: Water filled with modified flesh-eating bacteria - Water filled with malevolent nanobots.  I don't get how that is opposite...wouldnt benevolent nanomachines be opposite of a malevolent bacteria?   Or is it simply opposite because it's machine vs biological neglecting the malevolent part?  Is machine vs biological opposite?   Feels like a not well defined idea generation question

Comment: (yesterday): a little of both. (M i ech): good idea, I can just use glycerol. (Twelfth): Machinery vs. organic. They just need to mirror each other, yet be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- hydrofluoric acid/sodium hydroxide
  *Note: these two solutions will cause very similar reactions, despite being opposite agents.
- near-boiling dimethyl phthalate/ liquid nitrogen
- vibrio vulnificus (flesh-eating bacteria)/concentrated sanitizer disinfectant (see this site: http://www.kellysolutions.com/erenewals/documentsubmit/KellyData%5COK%5Cpesticide%5CMSDS%5C875%5C875-106%5C875-106_D10_Concentrate_3_17_2011_9_36_10_AM.pdf)
- radioactive agents (cause mutations, possibly cancer)/nanobots that destroy cancer cells (if there's no cancer, they'll kill healthy cells)
- liquid solution of cocaine/ liquid solution of morphine
  *Note: these two solutions will cause very similar reactions, despite being opposite agents.

I don't know about any others. Most things that can hurt you by contact are relieved simply by removing contact, and most cures are specifically designed not to become the next problem. Personally, I would say that "artificial poison" and "venom" aren't opposite because they are basically the same thing, but that's not really my call. If you count such things, you could do venom and antivenom because most antivenom is made from venom. I recommend using two types in this case, IE viper venom, mamba antivenom. I would also not count things like "bacteria" and "nanobots" if they both bring about the same result because they are basically the same thing. I would also recommend giving whoever contacts these chests a cut of some sort to expedite the effects of the substances.

Answer (score 1):

**I can't promise** that all of these situations are easy to reproduce - nor that they will look exactly like water - but presumably the hero will know after the first chest that they aren't water, so I'm going with "can look like a liquid if handwaved minimally"

- Acidic and alkaline
- Hot and cold
- Artificial toxin and natural venom
- Stimulant and depressant (hazardous drugs, topical)
- [Muon-powered fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon-catalyzed_fusion) and rapid fission
- Endothermic (taking energy) and exothermic (requiring energy)(chemical reactions)
- Bacteria (alternatively viruses) and nanobots
- Parasites (keep living) and decomposers
- Extremely magnetic (pulls) and *also extremely magnetic* (pushes)

Comment: For clarity not all of these are completely realistic / there is some handwaving involved but the OP can choose what is realistic enough for their setting